# Does SQL Server 2005 Log Shipping replicate changes to the master database schema and permissions?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

In a SQL Server 2005 database that is replicated using log shipping, will changes to the following be automatically reflected in the replicated database?

- Tables
- Stored Procedures
- Views
- Functions
- Object-level permissions
- Database roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With log shipping you end up with two *identical* databases, down to the last bit. Everything declared in the database gets shipped to the log shipping partner.